# Checking the status of a specific git id across jobs in Jenkins

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, jenkins

We are using Jenkins to continuously build our software across the 20 or so different platforms/configurations that we build on.  Some of those platforms are much slower than others, and the code doesn't always build cleanly on all platforms.

Is there a way to check the 'status' of a given git ID.  Ideally, I'd like to know for any ID on which platforms it's been built already, on which it was ok, and on which it failed.  Is that possible?

We don't use matrix jobs (we have one 'normal' job per platform).  This may come, but I didn't try that yet.  Would it help?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a Git ID ?

Comment: A Git ID is a way to uniquely identify a commit.  Similar to an SVN revision number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification - it would be easiest to use a matrix build, because then all of your builds in the matrix would get triggered by the same Git ID and you'd see the pass / fail status of each build in the matrix in one Jenkins page.

You can pull the change that triggered a build fairly easily from the Jenkins API, e.g. `http://myjenkins:8080/job/myjob/22/api/json` will give you all of the details for myjob build 22 in JSON format, including the revision that triggered it and the build result.  You could write a script to pull that info for all your builds if you don't want to set up a matrix build.

See `http://myjenkins:8080/job/myjob/22/api` for other available output formats.